# ash: command not found

Tags: unix, terminal, unison

On my NAS I have installed Unison package, which works when ssh'd into the NAS with this `$NAS unison -version`.

However when running the command locally without ssh'ing to the system first using `ssh remotehost unison -version` I get this error returned.

```
ash: unison: not found
```

Comment: Are you ssh'ing into your NAS with the same account as the local console? Have you installed unison into a directory that is not in your search path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check what is your path when ssh'ing to NAS:

```
ssh remotehost 'echo $PATH'
```

Then on the NAS check where is `unison` installed:

```
which unison
```

Most probably it will not be in the `ssh` path.

### Solutions

If the above described was the problem you can one of the following:

1. Specify full path: `ssh remotehost /full/path/unison`
2. Extend path: `ssh remotehost 'PATH="$PATH:/full/path" ; unison'`
3. Set the path in `ssh` if `PermitUserEnvironment` is enabled in `sshd` configuration. Add the `PATH` to: `~/.ssh/environment`
4. Execute the command inside a login shell on the NAS: `ssh remotehost 'ash -l -c "unison"'`

Comment: The full path needed to be specified, created a symbolic link to rectify.